# What is the wizard proficiency for the Spell Save DC

Tags: dnd-5e

What is the wizard proficiency for the Spell Save DC, is it the armour proficiency or what.

Comment: Welcome to the site! When you get a chance, please take the [tour]. I think it would make the question more clear if you were more specific about which passage of the PHB was unclear to you.

Answer (score 2):

Each class gives one stat called proficiency bonus. It starts at 2 and increases from there. It is added to a lot of things like attack rolls, skills you are proficient with and your spell save DC*.

For example see the wizard class [here](http://engl393-dnd5th.wikia.com/wiki/Wizard).

The spell save DC is 8+ proficiency bonus +casting stat modifier (int for the wizard)

*Among other things

Comment: Thanks! that was extremely helpful, now I can finish my character.